# Creating a test from Angular query parameter returned as a promise

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing

I have my TestBed configuration with the following provider:

```
{
provide: ActivatedRoute,
useValue: {
    queryParams: of({fooObservable: true})
  }
},
```

how can I write a jasmine spy that accesses this query parameter and tests whether it's true or false?  I have done the following but I can't access it in order to test it.
`fooSpy = spyOn(this.ActivatedRoute.queryParams, 'queryParams');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky.  Here is how I did it:

```
const spyParamMap = jasmine.createSpyObj({get: null});
const mockActivatedRoute = { paramMap: of(spyParamMap) };
```

Then in providers array: `{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute }`

And finally in tests:

```
spyParamMap.get.and.returnValue('tFilename');
fixture.detectChanges();
```

In my `ngOnInit()` I have the following snippet:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.dlFilename = params.get('download');
    if (this.dlFilename) {
         // logic for if a filename is passed
    }
```

so I can pass in a result to `params.get()` and test my logic inside the `if`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is great! So you basically wrap the jasmine spy object in an Observable and pipe that to whatever value tFilename is?

Comment: Close.  `route.paramMap` is a property of type Observable<ParamMap>.  ParamMap is an object with a `get()` method.  See [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap).  So to mock this I create a spy object that will be emitted from the Observable<ParamMap> which will get set as `params` in the `subscribe()` method.  I do this so I can later change the `.returnValue()` of the spy within the spy object (`get()` in this case) to whatever I want.  I ignore the value passed to `get()` in my spy - it would return 'tFilename' if it was called with `get('foo')`, but this is just for a test.